# Maven relocation for Tika API

Tags: java, maven, apache-tika, maven-shade-plugin

I'm trying to relocate all the Tika related classes into a new class using maven-shade-plugin as shown in the **example** below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <relocations>
                  <relocation>
                    <pattern>org.apache.tika</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>shaded.org.apache.tika</shadedPattern>
                  </relocation> 
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
<plugin>
```

**Dependencies in POM:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
   <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
   <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
   <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to use the shaded jar in my new project to read a file, there is no exception and i find nothing on the console . Am i missing something? Kindly Help!

**Sample Code:**

```
import shaded.org.apache.tika.Tika;

Tika tika = new Tika();
tika.setMaxStringLength(1000);
System.out.println(tika.parseToString(file));
```

Comment: Tika has services files that list the names of the classes to use. What happens if you update those with your new names too?

Comment: Also, what about the Tika dependencies?

Comment: I have added those dependencies in the POM which has the shaded plugin and built a fat jar out of it. I've imported the new jar in my new project.

Comment: You still need to update the service files to have the new names. Or clear out your classpath to not need the package relocation. Or use a proper solution for multiple jar versions like OSGi...